# Ionic android:navigationBarColor

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Is there a plugin or even better a **config.xml** option on how to set the android navigation bar color in `ionic v.3`?

I have already set up the status bar color on my application but would really like to style the bottom navigation as well.

Comment: The right place to ask this would be the **[Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/)**, not here.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your varibles.scss which is in src\theme add the following code

```
ion-navbar{
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in src/theme/variables.scss

```
$colors: (
   primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64
 )
```

Then in your html
Ion-navbar [color]="isNormal ? 'primary' : 'secondary'">